# C# code inside asp:button

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

Why won't this work?

in my page.aspx:

```
<% foreach(ws in workoutschedule){%>
<div><table><tr><td>
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" text="<%=ws.wsName%>" />
</td></tr></table></div> <%}%>
```

how do i do to show the wsName from the loop as the name of the asp:button, and how do i send that string to the code behind?

Comment: Did you try html button <input id='Button1' type='button' runat='server' text="<%=ws.wsName%>" />

Comment: yeah, that didn't work. It results in a blank text=""

Comment: May be you can put a place holder there and generate buttons on codebehind

Comment: well i want the buttons to be generated in the foreach loop in the asp page so that they will be able to link to different pages

Comment: code behind can do anything

Comment: @TonyDong is right, better to use code behind

Comment: Can I make divs from code behind?

Comment: Yes, you can add div in code behind. please see this URL for details.

http://www.devcurry.com/2009/01/dynamically-create-tag-using-server.html